# How do you import multiple build types of a native library with Android Maven Plugin

Tags: maven, android-ndk, android-maven-plugin

How do you import multiple build types of a the same native library with Maven?

A little context, I'm using the Android Maven Plugin, and I'm trying to import a native library that was build for several different CPU architectures. I read the post [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/NativeLibsAsDependencies) that shows how to declare the dependency, but I still have to install the .so files locally in my repository. I'm not confused on how to install third party libs into my local repository, I'm confused about how to name these things. For example, say we have the dependency:

```
<!-- Declare the dependency on a native library, already deployed in the Maven repository -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.acme.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>libsample_jni</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>so</type>
  </dependency>
```

The code that loads the library would be:

```
System.loadLibrary("sample_jni");
```

But let's say we have multiple builds of libsample_jni that target different CPU architectures. What naming convention would I use so that the libs are put in the right folders in my APK? Is this even a naming convention issue, since the plugin is responsible for this? Is there some tag I need to include in the dependency declaration to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the different binary artifacts for different CPU architectures should be differentiated by specifying distinct classifier values in their maven naming co-ordinates.
See http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates